# How do you work out $\sqrt{2} \pmod{31}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a^{n}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ with $n$ odd then $a^{n}=a^{1 + \frac{n-1}{2}\cdot 2}\equiv 1\pmod p$ so we have $a \equiv (a^{\frac{1-n}{2}})^{2} \pmod{p}$ and then we have $\sqrt{a}=a^{\frac{1-n}{2}} \pmod{p}$.

From this we have that since $2^{5}\equiv 1 \pmod {31}$ then $2 \equiv (2^{-2})^{2},$ so that $\sqrt{2}\equiv 2^{-2} \pmod {31}$.

I know that $2^{-2}\equiv 8 \pmod {31}$, (and this checks out since $8^2=64 \equiv2 \pmod{31}$) but I don't know how this was obtained and would like to know how do you see that $2^{-2} \equiv 8 \pmod{31}$ without guessing.

Comment: You meant to write $2\equiv (2^{-2})^2\pmod {31}$.   Other than that...what confuses you?  You have written out the entire computation and checked the result.

Comment: @lulu: Yes, that was a typo. My question is: I wanted to know how do you find out that $2^{-2} \equiv 8$?

Comment: Well, $2^{-1}\equiv {16}$, yes?  Since $2\times 16=32\equiv 1$.  But then $2^{-2}\equiv 16^2=256\equiv 8\pmod {31}$.

Comment: @lulu: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Might be worth saying:  with such small numbers, I'd be inclined to just go by trial and error.  Especially if you are doing this with a machine, that computation is fool proof and lightning fast. Granted, with large moduli you might want to search for other means.

Comment: Alternately, since $2^5\equiv1$, $2^{-2}\equiv2^3=8$. But note that all of these only work because $31=2^t-1$; in general computing square roots mod $n$ is known to be (exactly) as hard as factoring $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^{-2}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2^2=4$, so you need to solve the congruence $4x\equiv1$ mod $p$ with $p=31$. Solving for multiplicative inverses in general can be done with the Euclidean algorithm, but in this case the solution $x=8$ may jump out at you. If it doesn't, note that $4$, in general, divides either $p+1$ or $p-1$. If it divides $p+1$, then $(p+1)/4$ is the mulitplicative inverse; if it divides $p-1$, then $-(p-1)/4$ is the multiplicative inverse. (Alternatively, $(p+1)/2$ is always the multiplicative inverse of $2$, so $((p+1)/2)^2$ is always the multiplicative inverse of $4$, so here we get $16^2=256=31*8+8\equiv8$ mod $31$.)

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod {31} \implies x^2 - b^2 = (x-b)(x+b) \equiv 0\pmod {31}$ but as $31$ is prime there are no zero divisors and $x\equiv \pm b\pmod{31}$ are the only two options.

Now we know by FLT then $2^{30}\equiv 1 \pmod {31}$ and so the order of $2$, call it $k$, will divide into $30$.  So as $2^{km} \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$ then $2^{km + 1}\equiv 2 \pmod {31}$.  So if we can find a even value of $km + 1$ then we have $(2^{\frac {km+1}2})^2 \equiv 2^{km+1} \equiv 2 \pmod {31}$.

If $k$ is odd then we can just use $\frac {k+1}2$.  But if $k$ is even we are s.o.l and there won't get us anywhere.

SO first what *is* $k$ so that $k|30$ and $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$?  It's not too hard to see that then the order of $2$ is $k = 5$ and $2^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$.

And we are in luck $5$ is odd and so $(2^3)^2 \equiv 2^6 \equiv 2\pmod{31}$>

And so the only two solutions to $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {31}$ are $x \equiv \pm 2^3 \equiv \pm 8 \equiv 8, 23\pmod {31}$.

That's it.

Hmm I suppose I should explore if this wold be solvable for $\sqrt{m}$ where the order of $m$ is an even $k$....

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are asking if there is a smart way of extending modulo function to rational powers, or beyond.

The simplest solution is to use *offset*, but I guess from your description that is not what you have in mind. You want it as an operator in the sense of

$$\mathbb{E}^2a \equiv a^2 \mod m$$

Ok, but then look at this

$$\mathbb{E}^{\frac1{2}}a \equiv a^{\frac1{2}} \mod m$$

Start from the basic property that must be satisfied

$$\mathbb{E} \equiv \mathbb{E}^{\frac1{2}}\mathbb{E}^{\frac1{2}} \equiv \left ( \mathbb{E}^{\frac1{2}} \right )^2$$

This means that you are asking for quadratic residue (if it exists) over, in your case, $31$. You are asking what numbers have quadratic residue $2$ over $31$.

$$x \equiv 2 \mod 31$$
$$\sqrt{x}^2 \equiv 2 \mod 31$$

Notice that $\sqrt{2}$ is defined only by the property from the modulo function perspective:

$$(\sqrt{2})^2 \equiv 2 \mod 31$$

This does mean that $\sqrt{}$ is an abuse on notation, it should be $\mathbb{E}^{\frac1{2}}$.

The result is the series in form of $31k+8$ or $31k+23$ or put it together:

$$8, 23, 39,... 31k \pm 8, k \geq 2$$

Reducing to only $8$ and $23$ is technically wrong because even $\sqrt{x}=39$ satisfies

$$\sqrt{x}^2 \equiv 2 \mod 31$$

and any integer with that property is a square root of $2$ modulo $31$, and you have never specified which set we should choose the result from, so it is implicitly assumed that it is among integers, right?

All roots are defined through the opposite function $(\sqrt[n]{a})^n=a$ but you have to take into account its domain and what $=$ means within that domain.